# How to run VMWare player on kernel 2.6.38-8? [Failed to compile module vmmon]

Tags: 11.04, vmware

I upgraded my 10.04 system to 10.10 on my way to 11.04. I didn't try VMPlayer on 10.10, but it worked on 10.04.

I tried to start a VM in 11.04, and it prompted me to install the VMWare bits into the kernel. It would fail, and provide a log file. The log file looked normal until the end, at which point it said:

```
"Failed to compile module vmmon"
```

I found a number of references on the web for that, but all related to older versions of the kernel. The one I found for 2.6.38-8 was this patch:

[VMware-player on Ubuntu 11.04 kernel 2.6.38-8](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1745502)

but that is for 64 bit. I assume those header patches won't work on 32 bit (yes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution I used was to uninstall the old version, and install 3.1.4 from the VMWare site.

1. `sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player`
2. `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/vmware`
3. [Download and install VMPlayer 3.1.4](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/desktop_downloads/vmware_player/3_0)

Comment: This is the precise solution - VMware Player 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

The attached file says:
**VMplayer_3.0.0-203739.x86_64_2.6.38-8.tar.gz (3.1 K)** 
x86 means 32 bits system, ASFAIK. So you could try with this file. The other option is to run older kernel. I usually try with stable releases from here:
[Mainline kernel downloads](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)
BTW, I dont see 2.6.38-8 kernel there, is this the rc8 version?
I hope at least some of this info helps

Comment: Ah, you might be right that the package will work for 32bit. I didn't try that, so I can't confirm if that solution works. As for the kernel version, my install of 11.04 laid down 2.6.38-8-generic-pae.